# How to show zoom in/out button in react native maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a React Native app where i'm using `react-native-maps`. I have been showing maps with current location but i want to show the zoom in/out button like the default one in google maps. Is there any way to do that in `react-native-maps` or i would have to make one ?

Here's my code:

```js
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.0421;
const LATITUDE = 3.202424;
const LONGITUDE = 101.717247;
let { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
const timeout = 1000;
let animationTimeout;
export default class Map extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: LATITUDE,
      longitude: LONGITUDE,
      routeCoordinates: [],
      distanceTravelled: 0,
      prevLatLng: {},
      coordinate: new AnimatedRegion({
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0
      }),
      isModalVisible: false,
      vendors: [],
      vendorId:''
    }
  }
  async componentWillMount () {
    await this.locationData();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { coordinate } = this.state;

    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      position => {
        const { routeCoordinates } = this.state;
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

        const newCoordinate = {
          latitude,
          longitude
        };

        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
          if (this.marker) {
            this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
              newCoordinate,
              500
            );
          }
        } else {
          coordinate.timing(newCoordinate).start();
        }

        this.setState({
          latitude,
          longitude,
          routeCoordinates: routeCoordinates.concat([newCoordinate]),
          prevLatLng: newCoordinate
        });
      },
      error => console.log(error),
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000,
        distanceFilter: 10
      }
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
  }
  getMapRegion = () => ({
    latitude: this.state.latitude,
    longitude: this.state.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
  });

  locationData = async () => {
    let bodyData = {};
    try {
      let userInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userInfo');
      let latLng = await AsyncStorage.getItem('markerPosition');
      if (userInfo !== null && latLng !== null) {
        userInfo = JSON.parse(userInfo);
        latLng = JSON.parse(latLng);
        bodyData.customer_id = userInfo.customerId;
        bodyData.security_code = userInfo.userSecurityCode;
        bodyData.lat = 3.202424;
        bodyData.lng = 101.717247;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'api',
      data: bodyData,
      config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('check',response)
        if ('success' in response.data) {
          if ('data' in response.data) {
            let vendors = response.data.data;
            let vendorData = vendors.map(vendor => {
              return {
                id: vendor.vendor_id,
                title: vendor.company_name,
                lat: vendor.lat,
                lng: vendor.lng
              }
            });
            this.setState({
              vendors: vendorData,
            })
          } else {
            alert(response.data.success)
          }
        } else {
          alert(response.data.error)
        }
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function (error) {
        //handle error
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
  showMarkers = (vendors) => {
    return vendors.map((vendor, index) => {
      console.log('show',vendor)
      return (
        <MapView.Marker
          key={vendor.id}
          coordinate={{
            latitude: parseFloat(vendor.lat),
            longitude: parseFloat(vendor.lng)
          }}
          title={vendor.title}
          description={(this.state.categories)}
          pinColor='blue'
          onPress={() => this.focus(vendor)}
          onCalloutPress={() => this._toggleModal()}
        />
      )
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { vendors } = this.state
    return (
      <Container style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
        <Content>
          <View>
          <MapView
            ref={ref => { this.map = ref }}
            style={styles.mapContainer}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            showUserLocation
            followUserLocation
            loadingEnabled
            minZoomLevel={2}  // default => 0
            maxZoomLevel={15} // default => 20
            zoom={1}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            followUserLocation={true}
            showsMyLocationButton={true}
            zoomEnabled={true}
            enableZoomControl={true}
            zoomTapEnabled={true}
            region={this.getMapRegion()}
          >
            <Marker.Animated
              ref={marker => {
                this.marker = marker;
              }}
              coordinate={this.state.coordinate}
            />
          
          
           {this.showMarkers(vendors)}
          
            </MapView>
              </View>
        </Content>
      </Container>

    )
  }
}
```

Now i guess it has to be something with `animated region`. But where can i add this animated region in my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const [widthOfMap, setWidthOfMap] = useState(width);

<MapView  
 onMapReady={() => { setWidthOfMap(widthOfMap- 1) }}
>
</>
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations to questions and not posting purely code answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. For anyone trying this, the point is you need to set the Width style of the View that contains the MapView component to '0%' initially then use useState and onMapReady() to change Width back to '100%' when the map is fully loaded.
All buttons will appear normally.

Answer (score 0):

Use `animateToRegion` method from react-native-maps

make one object, add pass to region to set the zoomlevel

The `latitude` and `longitude` specifies the center location of the map and `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` specify the view area for map

```
region: {
                latitude: 11.2,
                longitude: 22.1,
                latitudeDelta: 0.005,
                longitudeDelta: 0.001
            }
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Can you tell me where to add this animateToRegion @Praveenkumar